# Power Query Time saved as Date

Tags: powerpivot, powerquery

I'm using Power Pivot to connect to data stored in a folder. The data is stored as csv files. I'm using Power Query to format the data and connect to Power Pivot...

I am having issues with my Time columns which export with time in the following format 02:33:00 PM... When I load Power Pivot and create a Pivot Table to get the average time I get an popup: "we cannot summarize this field with Average because it's not a supported calculation for Date data types"

My question is how can I convert these columns so that I can get average time (apparently they are being stored as dates even though in Power Query I have them as Time Only.

Thanks

Comment: Time values in Excel are decimal amounts between 0-1. Can you convert your times into decimal format in PQ and have them formatted as time in your output?

Comment: That fixed it - I was converting to Time in PQ instead of decimal... Thanks so much, just saved me a lot of time!